# taking a screenshot of a UIView in iOS

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, uiview

I'm running iOS 4.3 & trying to take a screenshot of a UIView which is playing a movie.
The problem is that the screenshot (in the simulator) turns out to be simply a black background & not the movie image i was hoping for. My code is below, any ideas what the matter might be? thanks in advance :)

```
- (void) takeScreenshot;
{

    UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(self.frame.size, NO, 0.0);
    [self.layer renderInContext:UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()];
    UIImage *screenshot = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();

    UIImageView *movieImage = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:screenshot];
    [self addSubview:movieImage];

}
```

Comment: I am not sure, but your problem may be in `[self.layer renderInContext:UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()];` because you taking the screenshot of the self.layer instead of your movieplayer view.

Comment: I expect that the movie view is using an OpenGL layer to draw its video, so this won't work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I eventually found a solution to this issue - as joerick mentioned above one can't take a screenshot (using renderInContext) as the movie is using an OpenGL layer to draw its video.

However there is a way to take a thumbnail of a movie (shown below for the current playback time):

```
UIImage *image = [moviePlayer thumbnailImageAtTime:moviePlayer.currentPlaybackTime timeOption:MPMovieTimeOptionNearestKeyFrame];
```

Hope this helps someone out :)

Comment: so no way to take the actual screenshot? I have very limited knowledge of OpenGL but [Apple Doc](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#qa/qa1704/_index.html) has some code to take screenshot. I am not able get this code compiled for me.